# How to disable extra space checking for google closure linter?

Tags: javascript, google-closure

Google closure linter will give warning for every line in the following code, since there is extra space after the key name. 
Is there a way to disable the extra space checking? I also can't find a document for configure .gjslintrc file.

I also can't find the right flag to use in the " gjslint --help" result.

```
var ngTemplatesOptions = {
    prefix    : '/',
    module    : 'lc.directive.tpls',
    standalone: false,
    htmlmin   : {
        collapseBooleanAttributes    : true,
        collapseWhitespace           : true,
        removeAttributeQuotes        : true,
        removeComments               : true, // Only if you don't use comment directives!
        removeEmptyAttributes        : true,
        removeRedundantAttributes    : true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes   : true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable specific errors using the `disable` flag. In your case, you would want to do the following:

```
gjslint --strict --disable 0001,0002 yourfile.js
```

Where, error code `0001` signifies extra space and error code `0002` signifies missing space. Depending on your situation, you might also want to ignore the indentation erorrs. In this case, you would want to add error code `0006` to the list.

Comment: For a list of error codes, see https://github.com/google/closure-linter/blob/master/closure_linter/errors.py